# Remove all references used

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am removing a property from a class in c# code. I want all the references of that property should be removed, else it is throwing build errors while building the solution.
Is there any short cut in visual studio to remove all the references while removing a field/property or I need to do it manually one by one?

Comment: This functionality is provided with ReSharper's 'Safe Delete' refactoring, but I don't believe there's currently a native way to do this in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: So sad.It will kill lot of my time then ....Is there any easy work around available?

Comment: Just mark it as `[Obsolete]` instead of breaking your code base. You could also mark it as `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` to keep it from showing up as an option in Intellisense.

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with each reference? Supposed it's used as the parameter to a method. What do you expect to replace it with? You're going to have lots of manual cleanup either way.

Comment: I want to remove all the references to the field/property

Answer (score -1):

I would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> refactor it as "asdfgh" and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and review each instance.

But if I'm really confident, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for Replace All on ".asdfgh".

Comment: if I have a code like asdfgh = "qwert" then I should be removing the whole line. not just asdfgh part